# Using servers to run nodes and mine

Tags: nodes, mining

I have a few spare servers and I would really like to use them as nodes and mines to help support monero.

Is this a) useful and b) worthwhile?

Best,

H

Answer (score 1):

I think almost any server would be capable of running a node, and this is useful in the sense of expanding the network. As far as mining, it's only worth it if the server's CPU is equipped with AES, if it is, then it's probably "worth it" to mine if your electricity costs are less than $0.15/kWh or so. Of course it's always useful to mine to help decentralize the network too, but if your mining at a loss you might just be better off buying XMR from an exchange.